# Postfix header_checks add X-Mailgun-Tag

Tags: postfix, regular-expressions, smtp-headers

I am trying to add in the postfix header_checks, using PREPEND, some X-Mailgun-Tag headers.

When using the following expressions in the header_checks, it applies without issues to all domain emails.

`/^From:.*@example.com.*/i PREPEND X-Mailgun-Tag: Newsletters`

But I'd like to restrict it only to a specific email address, something like info@example.com.

I tried
`/From:info@example.com/ PREPEND X-Mailgun-Tag: Newsletters`
but it does not work.
Which reg expression should I use?

Comment: Anyone? I also tried From:info@example.com but still does not work.

Comment: When asking about regular expression, always show an example of a string (here: header) that is failing to match as intended.

Answer (score 1):

There could be any number of white space characters between `From:` and `info@example.com` but your regular expression doesn't allow that. Use something like `[[:space:]]+` or `\s+` (depending on which regexp format you are using).